# SNMP GetNext Command

Tags: c, snmp, net-snmp

I am having a MIB which contain table structure and i have generate code for that with the help of mib2c command in the Net-SNMP Library

```
mib2c -c mib2c.create-dataset.conf IPsTable
```

It generates the two files `IPsTable.c` and `IPsTable.h`.

Actually when i send a command for `snmpwalk`

```
snmpwalk -v2c -c public localhost -Ci IPsTable
```

Its give an output thats states  "Error: OID not increasing "

I have traced the log and got to know that we receive only the GET NEXT request and the value of column field increases everytimes i got the request.

```
    case MODE_GETNEXT:
        var = request->requestvb;
        table_info = netsnmp_extract_table_info(request);
        snmp_log(LOG_INFO,"column : %d\n",table_info->colnum);
        snmp_log(LOG_INFO,"index : %d\n",*(table_info->indexes->val.integer));
        if (table_info->colnum > RESULT_COLUMN){
            table_info->colnum=0;
            return SNMP_ERR_NOERROR;
        }
        x=*(table_info->indexes->val.integer);
             

        netsnmp_table_build_result(reginfo, requests,
                                   table_info, ASN_INTEGER,
                                   (u_char *) & result,
                                       sizeof(result));
        break;
```

Problem arises when the value of column exceed from the number of column we have in MIB's row and its keeps on increasing. I was not been able to increment the value of index.

Is there any way so that i can reset the value of column and incement the value of index (means pointing to next row) ?